# @SecondaryTable Mapping from primary table (compsite primary key) to secondary table (single primary key)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, composite-primary-key

Table :`person`

```
id (pk)  
first_name  
last_name
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="birthDate")
    private String birthDate;

    @Column(name="detail")
    private String detail;
}
```

Table :`activity`

```
id(pk)
name;
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="activity")
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="activity_id")
    private List<PersonRole> personRoleList;
}
```

Table :`person_role`

```
activity_id 
person_id 
role_name
pk(activity_id,person_id)
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person_role")
public class PersonRole {


        @Id
        PersonRolePK personRolePk;


    //  private String personName; /* I want this value to be loaded form person table using the person_id when a PersonRole is reader from database */


        @Column(name="role_name")
        private String roleName;

}


@Embeddable
public class PersonRolePK implements Serializable
{
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="activity_id")
    public String activityId;

    @Column(name="person_id")
    public String personId;

}
```

This is working well for me when i am storing data in database

It also work as expected and load all related PersonRole when i want to the Activity from database

Now in Addition I want to fill the `personName` field of class `PersonRole`(commented) from the table `person` when the PersonRole is being loaded.

I read about `@SecondaryTable` annotation and approached with it.

But the problem is all the tutorials and documentations  also this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2235) show
that it is necessary to have the same number of primary key field (if composite key) in both of the table if i want to map the secondary table and those filed will be mapped using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

But in my case there is no need to use multiple key as the Person has single primary key

So Is there any way to map a table containing composite primary key to with table containing single primary key to use `@SecondaryTable`?

OR,

Is there any other good approach to achieve what i want.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in this situation I would have a OneToMany relationship in the Activity and Person pojo's. And in the PersonRole pojo you would have a ManyToOne relationship for each of Activity and Person, which lets you get at all the data you need without duplicating of data (personname).

Add a OneToMany in the Person pojo.

```
Set<PersonRole> personRoles = new HashSet<PersonRoles>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person")
public Set<PersonRole> getPersonRoles() {
   return this.personRoles;
}
public void setPersonRoles(Set<PersoneRole> personRoles) {
   this.personRoles = personRoles;
}
```

Add a ManyToOne relationship in the PersonRole pojo.

```
Private Person person;
Private Activity activity;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
public Person getPerson() {
   return this.person;
}
public void setPerson(Person person) {
   this.person = person;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "activity_id")
public Activity getActivity() {
   return this.activity;
}
public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
   this.activity = activity;
}
```

You should now be able to get the name out of Person when querying on Activity.

Comment: i must say this is a good way. But i need only the `first_name` and `last_name` not the reference of `Person` it self. and `Person` pojo can have some other field like `birthDate``detail` ( i apologize i did not add those in the question )

Comment: can i get some selective field using ManyToOne?